# Can't install openssh under ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssh, apt-get

I am just trying to install openssh-client and openssh-server on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

When I do

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

I get the following:

http://pastebin.com/YJp04iin

(I pasted it on pastebin since it would have been too long otherwise).

I have really no idea on what is going on.

Comment: as it says, try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` also check `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I tried running both, I still get a huge output with errors. Should I paste those as well? They look quite similar, however.

Comment: Lines 12/13 in your pastebin are the trigger for the remainder of the errors. What's in that referenced error report? Please check lines 16-18 or so and remove the files it mentions.

Comment: @roaima here is the paste of that file: http://pastebin.com/rDMF1Nu1

Comment: @roaima are you referring to /etc/texmf/updmap.d ? Should I delete that one file? It is the only file it mentions on line 16, and no other file is mentioned in the next two lines..

Comment: [This bug report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1236951/comments/11) may help. Don't action it verbatim but rather, use its process to solve the 12 or so errors at the end of your updmap.d pastebin.

Comment: Is this after an upgrade from 12.04? If so, it's [this bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454550/ignoring-etc-texmf-texmf-d-cnf-during-generation-of-texmf-cnf-when-installi) that's answered on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @roaima it was an upgrade from 12.04. That actually solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21423/discussion-between-matteo-monti-and-roaima).

Answer (score 0):

I would start with removing all latex packages and after that i would try dpkg --configure -a 
did you interrupt apt / dpkg before that?

Answer (score 0):

Answering from the comment thread.

If this is upgrade from 12.04 then it's a bug that has previously been answered successfully on Ask Ubuntu. Here's the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/454550/ignoring-etc-texmf-texmf-d-cnf-during-generation-of-texmf-cnf-when-installi